# Solution For Multiple Backgrounds?

Tags: css

I can always nest a div inside of a div and apply different backgrounds to both but is there a better way to do this now that is supported well enough to replace that solution?

Comment: Define "supported well enough".

Comment: not exactly sure what you want... you want different backgrounds on 2 divs, or change backgrounds by using 2 divs?

Comment: You always have to be careful about appearing to ask a subjective question...

Comment: I'm trying to use 2 backgrounds.. 1 a tiled BG and 1 being a radial gradient starting at the top of the website.  Usually I would apply the tiled BG to the body tag and then add the gradient to the first div after the body tag. So I'm asking is there a better way to do this that is supported by a wide range of browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you had applied a class to your body tag, and then based on what background you want to show up, you apply that class.

```
.backgrounda{
background-image:url('a.jpg');
}

.backgroundb{
background-image:url('b.jpg');
}
```